# How to display package upgrade details on command line?

Tags: 10.04, server, package-management

On desktop machines, the Update Manager application is able to show the details of a package upgrade in the section called "Description of update" in the bottom half of the screen. Is there a way to see this information for a server machine using the command line?

Comment: You can try playing around with aptitude - The text-based package manager. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `apt-listchanges`, it will show the changes through pager and also mail them (to root, I think).

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the names of upgradable packages, obtained by

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p
```

with the packages description obtained by `apt-cache`. Here is a script that do that:

```
#!/bin/bash

{ /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -p 2>&1; echo; } |
  while read pkg; do
    echo "Package: " $pkg
    echo "Description:"
    apt-cache --no-all-versions show $pkg | 
      awk '/^ /'
    echo
  done
```

Some difficulties resolved above are that `apt-check -p` send output to stderr and do not write a newline on the last line.